# spfx peoplepicker- change state on remove suggestion

Tags: web-part, spfx, spfx-webparts, people-picker

I want to change a state when the user remove a person from people picker?

```
  <NormalPeoplePicker
                onChange={this._onChange.bind(this)}
                onResolveSuggestions={this._onFilterChanged}
                getTextFromItem={(persona: IPersonaProps) => persona.primaryText}
                pickerSuggestionsProps={suggestionProps}
                className={'ms-PeoplePicker'}
                key={'normal'}
                itemLimit={1}
                // defaultSelectedItems={this.state.selectedItems}
                onRemoveSuggestion={}

              />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to use the onChange method on the component
private _onChange = (items: IPersonaProps[]) => {
    this.setState({
      selectedItems: items
    });
  }
See my detailed post regarding this implementation http://www.thesharepointguide.com/sharepoint-framework-office-ui-fabric/

Hope this helps

Comment: Thaks, that solve my problem, do you know maybe how to set a default value when the people picker loads?

Comment: Set the defaultSelectedItems with the default value(s) in the people picker component. Also ensure the state is also set to the same default value so that it is consistent with the rest of the UI